# What is the best way to filter the dictionaries value in the list and remove that dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

For example I have dictionaries inside list,

```
student_list = [{'name':'ABC', 'marks': 8}, {'name':'DEF', 'marks': 0}, {'name': 'GHI', 'marks': 0}, {'name': 'JKL', 'marks': 0}, {'name': 'JKL', 'marks': 9}]
```

Output should be like,

```
[{'name':'ABC', 'marks': 8}, {'name': 'JKL', 'marks': 9}]
```

What is the best way to do this.

I can use `forloop` to get this output but i want to cater this with the python built_in function or handle this without using `forloop`.

Comment: Please be specific: you want the dictionaries where the value associated with the key `'marks'` is not zero?

Comment: Please don't put "forloop" in code formatting. `forloop` is a name, not code

Comment: We don't do your homework. Please read [ask]. You must show your research and what you've tried. Please make your question more clear. By the power of the close vote, I close this question!

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension.

```
print [i for i in student_list if i['marks'] > 0]
```

As suggested in the comments, you can also use

```
print [i for i in student_list if i.get('marks', 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something a bit advanced like:

```
print filter(lambda x: True if x['marks'] > 0 else False, student_list)
```

But this is really just an equivalent of the list comprehensions that were already suggested. See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) relevant section of the docs.